# "active" option doesn't change selected tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery mobile (not jQuery UI). What I would like to do is to change active tab without triggering click.

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="settingsPage">
    <div data-role="content">
        <div data-role="tabs" id="tabs">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a id="tab0" href="#one" class="ui-btn-active">Tab One</a></li>
                    <li><a id="tab1" href="#two">Tab Two</a></li>
                    <li><a id="tab2" href="#three">Tab Three</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="one" style="display: none" class="ui-body-d ui-content">Tab One content</div>
            <div id="two" style="display: none" class="ui-body-d ui-content">Tab Two content</div>
            <div id="three" style="display: none" class="ui-body-d ui-content">Tab Three content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
var tabIndex = 0;

setInterval(function(){

  tabIndex++;
  if (tabIndex >= 3)
     tabIndex = 0;
  else if (tabIndex < 0)
     tabIndex = 2;

  $("#tabs").tabs( "option", "active", tabIndex );

}, 3000);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t6v7ermu/1/)

What happens is the tab content is switching, but the active tab doesn't. How can I switch both, without initiating click event and leveraging jQuery Mobile/UI as much as possible?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t6v7ermu/3/

Comment: ok, so now it's confirmed that active tab selection is done by css and not by option->active. Thanks Omar!

Comment: tabs widget is imported from jquery-ui into jQM. ui doesn't add active class, but jQM does. This can be fixed as I showed you or you can change original code in jQM js file. Edit: you can add `.focus()` http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/aqbbw6zy/2/

Comment: So the other way would be to import jquery-ui script after/before jQM in html header?

Comment: No need to add jquery-ui; the widget is already included in jQM. https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/tree/master/external/jquery-ui/widgets

Comment: To summarize what I understood. When using jQM, tabs widget is trimmed and not including the code for changing active class. But if I use ONLY jquery-ui full version, then it's done there and I don't have to do anything additional to change active class of tab.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143755/discussion-between-omar-and-pablo).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `addClass` and `removeClass` for `ui-btn-active` class on `$("#tab" + tabIndex)`. Use `removeClass` before incrementing `tabIndex` and `addClass` after incrementing.

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f0xuxdvt/).

**UPDATE**

You can show the content in the tab based on the `tabIndex` by using a **switch statement**. Hide all tab content before `tabIndex` is incremented then based on `tabIndex` show tab content.

Here's the new [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4e6p179y/).

**UPDATE 2**

Thanks to [Omar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1771795/omar), you can **remove** and **add** the `ui-btn-class` on the `tabsactivate` event. I've updated the original fiddle with what [Omar has in the comments](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/aqbbw6zy/2/). This is the newest [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0zbah0fv/).

Here's the `tabsactivate` event that you need to add to your code:

```
$("#tabs").on("tabsactivate", function(e, ui) {
  ui.oldTab.find("a").removeClass("ui-btn-active");
  ui.newTab.find("a").addClass("ui-btn-active").focus();
});
```

Comment: Basically option->activate is not intended for changing tab selection

Comment: So you want to remove `$("#tabs").tabs( "option", "active", tabIndex );` from your code?

Comment: no, I would like it to work for me. But it looks like it will not change the tab button itself, rather only the tab content.

Comment: add this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/aqbbw6zy/2/ to your answer and get some rep.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the help Omar. You deserve the majority of the credit!

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you simulate the click?

`$("#tab"+tabIndex).click();`

instead of

`$("#tabs").tabs( "option", "active", tabIndex );`

Comment: because I have another code already triggering click for different reason and I thought for just changing active tab I can use option->active.